# connection symbols in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, symbols

I want to add some javascript in wordpress, something like

```
if(iNum==0&&iNum+1!=l)
```

It shows up wrong, in the source code I found `&` became `&#038;` how do I solve it? Thanks.

```
if(iNum==0&#038;\&#038; iNum+1!=l)
```

Comment: Where did you enter this? What did you expect?

Comment: the admin panel- pages-add new. then I add some js effect and output wrong. I wonder to know how to make it correct and that my js code can run well?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put that code?

To insert arbitrary javascript code, you need to use `HTML` mode in post / page edit window.
To do that, just click on 'HTML' just above editor window (to the right of `Upload/Insert` tools)

Comment: I add Exec-PHP plungin and edit it in  'HTML' as you said. but when it can not, I also search `amp` in wordpress.org, there are many other people also have this problem.